# How do I override root Bootstrap CSS variables when using CDN?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using a CDN to import Bootstrap 5 CSS. Bootstrap contains a bunch of different root CSS variables that are used by the components.

Here is my code:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <style>
        :root {
            --bs-primary: red;
        }
    </style>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">
        i should be red but im not
    </button>
```

I was assuming that this would apply the `--bs-primary` color to all of the bootstrap components, but it doesn't. I've tried placing the custom var declaration above the CDN link, and even adding `!important`. Nothing seems to work.

[According to the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/css-variables/#root-variables) I should be able to do this. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Also try clearing browser cache and reload, or use incognito/private mode to ensure cache is not interfering.

Comment: your variable name is overriding the color to red. you can check in browsers inspect and check in :root, [data-bs-theme=light] . if you hover on the --bs-primary it will show you red. The issue here is the btn styles(--bs-btn-bg:#0d6efd) are already set using default color system and after that you are trying to change it. Hope this explanation helps. to solve this, you have to download it and customize. customization : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color/